# JavaScript game not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I am building a memory game like Simon. My problem is that after the first turn it reads everything else as incorrect even after reading it as correct. It also repeats it multiple times in the console. I can't figure out why this is happening. I believe the problem lies somewhere in the player_turn and check_move functions.

All of my JavaScript code is below:

```
var sqrArray =['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']; 

var game = {
    count: 0,
    sequence: [],
    is_strict: false
}

// get random array element
function random_sqr() {
  return sqrArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
} 

// adds and remove green background
function makelight(n) {
  $('#' + n).addClass('light');
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('#' + n).removeClass('light');
  }, 300);
}

// assignes makelight() in order of array elements
function play() {
var i = 0;
var sequenceInter = setInterval(function() {
    makelight(game.sequence[i]);
    i++;
    if(i>=game.sequence.length) {
        clearInterval(sequenceInter);
    }
   }, 600);
}

// adds random sqr to game
function addToSequence() {
  game.sequence.push(random_sqr());
}

function play_game() {
  game.count++
  game.sequence.push(random_sqr());
  play();
}
var checkCount = 0;

//player picks sqr
function player_pick() {
  play_game();
  player_turn();
}

function player_turn() {
  if(checkCount < game.sequence.length) {
    check_move();
  } else {
    checkCount = 0;
    player_pick();
    console.log('The end!');
    console.log('check: ' + checkCount);
  }
}

// Checks player choice
function check_move() {
  $('.sqr').click(function() {
    if(this.id === game.sequence[checkCount]) {
      console.log('Correct!');
      checkCount++;
      console.log('after increment ' + checkCount);
      player_turn();
    } else if(this.id !== game.sequence[checkCount]) {
      console.log('incorrect');
      console.log('Array ' + game.sequence[checkCount]);
    }
  })
}

player_pick();
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="sqr" id="one" ></div>
<div class="sqr" id="two"></div>
<div class="sqr" id="three"></div>
<div class="sqr" id="four"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are seeing in your code is caused by the `check_move` function registering click handlers multiple times: each time you call that function, an additional handler is registered, and all are called when a click happens.

To fix this, only call `$('.sqr').click` once.